# How can my pomeranian tolerate being alone for roughly 12 days?

Tags: dogs, travel

I have a 4 year old pomeranian, in a family of 5.

4 of us will be going on vacation for roughly 12 days, and we are concerned about the pomeranian's tolerance to being alone.

The fifth person will be staying, but he due to work he has to be outside for half the day.

I am not really keen of leaving my dog with somebody else. Unless that's really necessary.

The fifth person says he will take her out every day, at least. Is it reasonable to leave my pomeranian alone for roughly 12 hours every day for 10+ days?

Comment: The only answer I can give is "that depends on the dog."

Comment: You could also take the dog to day care on say 6 of the 12 days. I have watched my dog being alone at home while we are at work. All she does is sleep

Comment: Only you can answer whether or not the dog's bladder can handle it. May want to consider potty-pads.

Answer (score 2):

The only way go find out how the dog will handle it is to either try it, or to deliberately take progressively longer absences so the dog has time to get used to the idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting a friend who works from home to come over to just sit on the sofa with a laptop for a few hours a day, and interact with the dog part of that time?  Then the responsibility wouldn't weigh so heavily on the shoulders of the fifth person, and you'd have more peace of mind.

Comment: This does not appear to address the question.

Comment: @JamesJenkins, I guess my answer to the question as stated would be no.  There is an implied question, how do I set things up so my dog isn't miserable, and that's what I focused on.